# Fixed Resolution in Flutter and Flame for Browser on PC

Tags: flutter, flame

I have started to develop a small game with Flutter and Flame. However, I have a problem: how can I define a maximum resolution for my game for users who might be on a browser on a PC (since my game is a platformer) so that the experience will be the same no matter how large the screen is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From reading your comment to the other answer I think I know what you are looking for, and that is the `FixedSizeViewport` if you are using the `CameraComponent` (which I suggest that you do), if you are using the legacy camera it is called `FixedResolutionViewport`.

When creating the `CameraComponent` you can use the specific constructor for this to have it set up this viewport for you (or you can set the viewport manually afterwards):

```dart
final cameraComponent = CameraComponent.withFixedResolution(
  width: 800,
  height: 600,
  world: world,
);
```

Comment: Can you help me know where to put this line in my code? The documentation is not very clear.

Comment: Are you using the `CameraComponent` already?

Comment: No, but i'm trying to do

`final world = World();
  late final CameraComponent cameraComponent;

  GameManager() {
    _mainScreen = MainScreen(() {
      remove(_mainScreen);
      _gameScreen = GameScreen();
      add(_gameScreen);
    });
  }

  @override
  Future<void>? onLoad() {

    cameraComponent = CameraComponent.withFixedResolution(width: 800, height: 600);

    cameraComponent = CameraComponent(world: _mainScreen);
    addAll([cameraComponent, _mainScreen]);

    add(_mainScreen);
  }`

Comment: You are creating two `CameraComponent`s here, pass in the world to the first one (`CameraComponent.withFixedResolution(width: 800, height: 600, world: world);`) and remove the second `CameraComponent`, and if your `MainScreen` is part of the game it should be added to the `world`, not directly to the `FlameGame`.

Comment: It's working, thanks, but on Chrome, the game is displaying at a random position (at the bottom right) even with a real size, any idea why ?

Comment: The center of the world is 0,0 by default, when adding your game to the FlameGame 0,0 is in the upper left corner. If you are not moving the camera, the easiest solution is the change the ViewFinder anchor:
`cameraComponent.viewfinder.anchor = Anchor.topLeft;`

Comment: Thank you very much ! 

Does this mean that larger screens than this resolution will have black bars? How do I set a maximum size with a ratio to respect?

Comment: Yes, that is what it means, the aspect ratio between the width and height will be respected and it will be scaled up/down accordingly.
Can you press the checkmark on the post to mark it as the answer? :)

Answer (score 0):

How do you define "**maximum game size**"?
How about the aspect ratio? Can it be played in portrait mode, or just on horizontal screens?

there are a lot of constraints we can work on just to decide how we show our game area.
In the old days, the game would have fixed size and aspect ratio, usually 4:3 size, and it would scale, depending on the width or the height of the screen, in a way it wouldn't deform the game.

Nowadays there are better ways to do that.
Since you want to create a platformer, there's not a big difference in the gameplay depending on the size of the screen, except if you create a game for very big screens, which would put a big tool on players with lower resolution screens, that probably won't be able to see the full scene.

Just be aware that if your game has too much resolution, and too much happening at the same time, bigger screens will suffer performance issues, because Flutter is not exactly an efficient Game dev platform.

My advice is to make the game area in the lowest resolution possible, but in a way it can still have good art, and scale it to bigger screens, keeping the resolution.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed response and the insights.

To clarify my original question, I'm specifically looking to set a maximum size limit for the game's display area when played on a browser on a PC. I want to prevent the game from taking up the entire screen, so it maintains a consistent appearance and doesn't become too stretched or distorted on larger displays.